# Warning: Unresponsive Script error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, my script seems to be getting this warning message whenever I run it.

This happens when I call a jquery function in the script. I have included the script below and put - Warning: Unresponsive Script - comment where I called the function. I don't really know why I'm getting the warning message.

Here is the project Im working on, if you want to see it [Click Here](http://jsbin.com/upiki)

I am trying to update the pagination numbers when filter options are selected. So when you select the color 'yellow' you get one result, which is 'giant' and there should only be 1 page number displayed as opposed to the 4.

If anyone has any ideas to get this working properly that would be amazing. Thanks.

JQuery Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

function paginateIt(){
 //how much items per page to show
 var show_per_page = 3; 
 //getting the amount of elements inside content div
 var number_of_items = $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().size();

 //calculate the number of pages we are going to have
 var number_of_pages = Math.ceil(number_of_items/show_per_page);

 //set the value of our hidden input fields
 $('#current_page').val(0);
 $('#show_per_page').val(show_per_page);

 //now when we got all we need for the navigation let's make it '

 /* 
 what are we going to have in the navigation?
  - link to previous page
  - links to specific pages
  - link to next page
 */
 var navigation_html = '<a class="previous_link" href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>';
 var current_link = 0;
 while(number_of_pages > current_link){
  navigation_html += '<a class="page_link" href="javascript:go_to_page(' + current_link +')" longdesc="' + current_link +'">'+ (current_link + 1) +'</a>';
  current_link++;
 }
 navigation_html += '<a class="next_link" href="javascript:next();">Next</a>';

 $('#page_navigation').html(navigation_html);

 //add active_page class to the first page link
 $('#page_navigation .page_link:first').addClass('active_page');

 //hide all the elements inside content div
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().css('display', 'none');

 //and show the first n (show_per_page) elements
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().slice(0, show_per_page).css('display', 'block');

// Start filter script
(function($) {

  $.fn.randomize = function(){
    return $(this).sort(function() {return 0.5 - Math.random()});
  }

  $.fn.filterprojects = function(settings) {
    settings = $.extend({
      animationSpeed: 900,
      animationPulse: 100,
      animationEase: "linear",
      activeClass: "active",
      allTag: "all",
      randomize: true,
      show: { width: "show", opacity: "show" },
      hide: { width: "hide", opacity: "hide" },
      filterTagSelector: [] // specify at least one 
      }, settings);

      $(this).each(function(i, o){
        var _elements = $(this).children();

        /* Binding the filter */
        $(this).bind("filter", function(){
          var _groups = [];
          var _filtered_elements = _elements;
          $.each(settings.filterTagSelector, function(k, j){
            _groups[k] = [];
            $(this + "." + settings.activeClass).each(function(){ 
              if(!$(this).hasClass(settings.allTag) && this.hash != undefined) { _groups[k].push(this.hash.substring(1)); }
            });
            if(_groups[k].length > 0){
              _filtered_elements = _filtered_elements.filter("." + _groups[k].join(",.")); 
            }
          });

          /* Randomize */
          if(settings.randomize){
            _filtered_elements = _filtered_elements.randomize();
            _elements = _elements.randomize();
          }
          /* Show */
          _filtered_elements.each(function(i,o){
            $(this).queue(function(){
              $(this).animate({left: "+0"}, (settings.animationPulse*i)); // dirty trick :)
              $(this).animate(settings.show, settings.animationSpeed);
              $(this).dequeue()
            });
          });

          /* Hide */
          _elements.not(_filtered_elements).each(function(i,o){
            $(this).queue(function(){
              $(this).animate({left: "+0"}, (settings.animationPulse*i)); // dirty trick :)
              $(this).animate(settings.hide, settings.animationSpeed);
              $(this).dequeue()
            });
          });
        });
        /* Setup filter selectors */
        $.each(settings.filterTagSelector, function(k, j){
          $(""+this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).hasClass(settings.allTag)){
              $(j).removeClass(settings.activeClass);
              $(this).addClass(settings.activeClass);
            } else {
              $(this).hasClass(settings.activeClass) ? $(this).removeClass(settings.activeClass) : $(this).addClass(settings.activeClass);
              $(j+"."+settings.activeClass).length > 0 ? $(j+"."+settings.allTag).removeClass(settings.activeClass) : $(j+"."+settings.allTag).addClass(settings.activeClass);
            }
            /* Triggering the filter */ 
            $(o).trigger("filter");
          })
        });
      });      
      return this
    };

// Warning: Unresponsive Script
paginateIt();


})(jQuery); // End filter script

} // End PaginateIt script
paginateIt();


}); // End of JS script.

function previous(){

 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
 //if there is an item before the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').prev('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}

function next(){
 new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) + 1;
 //if there is an item after the current active link run the function
 if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
  go_to_page(new_page);
 }

}
function go_to_page(page_num){
 //get the number of items shown per page
 var show_per_page = parseInt($('#show_per_page').val());

 //get the element number where to start the slice from
 start_from = page_num * show_per_page;

 //get the element number where to end the slice
 end_on = start_from + show_per_page;

 //hide all children elements of content div, get specific items and show them
 $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().css('display', 'none').slice(start_from, end_on).css('display', 'block');

 /*get the page link that has longdesc attribute of the current page and add active_page class to it
 and remove that class from previously active page link*/
 $('.page_link[longdesc=' + page_num +']').addClass('active_page').siblings('.active_page').removeClass('active_page');

 //update the current page input field
 $('#current_page').val(page_num);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Holy smokes... Have you tried profiling this in Firebug?

Comment: yes, the issue seems to the init() function in the jquery.min.js file with 12,825 calls at 29.03%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unresponsive Script Fix

It looks like you're just calling `paginateIt` recursively. The `paginateIt` function does a bunch of work and then calls itself again, infinitely.

To fix this, remove the call to `paginateIt()` just below your comment "Warning: Unresponsive Script" comment.

Here's the simplified structure of your code so that you can see the problem more clearly:

```
function paginateIt(){

    // Start filter script
    (function($) {

        $.fn.filterprojects = function(settings) {
            $(this).each(function(i, o){
                /* Binding the filter */
                /* Setup filter selectors */
            });      
        };

        // Warning: Unresponsive Script
        paginateIt();

    })(jQuery); // End filter script

} // End PaginateIt script

paginateIt();
```

### Re-pagination Fix

I would have written this line of code:

```
//getting the amount of elements inside content div
var number_of_items = $('#content ul').filter(":not(.hidden)").children().size();
```

as this:

```
var number_of_items = $('#content ul').children().filter(":visible").length;
```

Also, you'll want to call `paginateIt` after the animation completes for that to work correctly. You'll probably want to do this in an animation callback, but here's a temporary workaround:

```
/* Triggering the filter */ 
$(o).trigger("filter");
setTimeout(paginateIt, 1500);
```

Comment: This does solve the warning message, but any ideas on how I can call the script properly so the numbers update to the content when filter options are selected.

Comment: Sorry: I'm having a hard time following your code, and I'm not going to write your code for you, but I updated my answer with some more tips that should get you going down the right path.